# Select rows based on datetime columns of the same month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to compare 2 datetime columns in pandas and select those that do not have the same month. I cannot find a good source for working with datetime fields in theis a way and I attempted the standard gdf.loc[(gdf[Field1] != gdf[Field2])] but when I add .month, .dt.month, or pd.to_datime/pd.to_datetimeIndex it givesme a series error has no attribute. The 2 columns are datetime objects.

```
import geopandas as gpd, pandas as pd, datetime

Field1 = 'TrackStartTime'
Field2 = 'TrackEndTime'

gdf = gpd.read_file('Tracks.gpkg', driver='GPKG', layer='segments')
gdf.loc[~(gdf[Field1] == gdf[Field2])]
print(gdf[[Field1, Field2]])
```

Comment: There can be no doubt that .dt.month converts a datetime series to a series of integer values. Maybe you need to check if the 2 columns really have the expected format.

Comment: print(gdf.dtypes) shows the columns as object and print(gdf[Field1, Field2]) produces rows of 2019-04-08T18:45:00+00:00 type dates.

Comment: Apparently I needed to convert it to_datetime; must of had something wrong when I tried it the first time. gdf.loc[(pd.to_datetime(gdf[Field1]).dt.month == pd.to_datetime(gdf[Field2]).dt.month)]